# Yii How to render Users page using Id in model, but username instead of ID in URL

Tags: php, url, yii, url-rewriting

I have Users pages.
In index view they all have hyperlinks on ID, and so they are sending ID to model.
And when u press the link the users View is loaded and the url becomes

`/site/users/1`

But what I want is the URL to be not users ID but users Username like

`/site/users/Alex`

How can I do it ?
This is my _view

```
<?php echo CHtml::link(CHtml::encode($data->id), array('view', 'id'=>$data->id)); ?>
```

Controller

```
public function actionView($id)
{
    $this->render('view',array(
        'model'=>$this->loadModel($id),
    ));
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You will need to modify the following files :-

main.php(config)

```
"urlManager" => array(
    "rules" => array(
        "/site/users/<name:[\w\_]>" => "/site/users/view",
        //All the other rules here...
    )
)
```

Controller

```
public function actionView($name){
    $mdoel = User::model()->findByAttributes(array(
        "username" => $name
    ));
    if($model){
        $this->render("view", array(
            "model" => $model
        ));
    }
}
```

And wherever you are putting a link, make the link as follows :-

```
<?php echo CHtml::link(CHtml::encode($data->id), array("view", "name" => $data->username)); ?>
```

Update :-

Try using the following syntax :-

```
<?php echo Chtml::link(CHtml::encode($data->id), $this->createUrl('view', array('name'=>$model->username))); ?>
```

Comment: links are working but I have problems with URL.
WHen I entered config I saw that there everything is written in the way controller/action etc. not like "site/users"
So I'm trying to write there this 
<controller:\w+>/<action:\w+>/<name:[\w\_]>'=>'<controller>
but when I press hyperlink, url becomes this
mysite/users/view?name=123
how can I make it 
mysite/users/123  < that way ?

Comment: even "/site/users/<name:[\w\_]>" => "/site/users/",
gives me site/users/view?name=123 instead of site/users/123. Is there any way to fix it ?

Comment: that doesn't work at all. I think the first version was OK, we just need to think what to write in config, because it was working.